# Unity HTML5(WebGL) exported project not working on mobile/tablet

Tags: android, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have developed a few sample projects in Unity and was testing various platforms. I have exported the projects to HTML5 and was trying to access them from various devices.

They work perfectly on desktops (Chrome & Firefox), but they are not working on mobile phones and tablets. I have tried both Chrome & Firefox on mobile phones and tablets.
Now the HTML5 & WebGL samples available online (viz. http://webglsamples.org/ & https://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl) are working on mobiles and tablets.

I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in exporting these projects or something else..

Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, Unity's WebGL is not yet supported by mobile's browser.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/966721/unity5-webgl-for-mobile-browsers.html

I'm also developing game with Unity. If you want to build mobile game by using Unity, you better build it as mobile platform. (iOS/Android)

Comment: I have gone thru those articles...was wondering if someone else was able to port to HTML5/WebGL successfully...Thanks for the reply...Tchao!

Comment: @Apoorv Somebody already develop and release Unity's WebGL game. There also some article about Unity's WebGL [here](http://www.slideshare.net/LiorTal1/lessons-learned-with-unity-and-webgl). Me too, I hope I can release WebGL Game (which port from Mobile version) in the near future :)

Comment: Recently we developed toolchain that help to export Unity-made game to HTML5 content, here is the first demo we release last week. http://www.cyberytech.com:5000/mw2/ this is a coc style game, support iOS8 or Android 4.4+( not PC-compatible now)

Answer (score 3):

Recently our team developed toolchain that help to export Unity-made games to HTML5 contents. The toolchain is in its early stage, there still a lot to be done, but our team is focus on it and the progress is good.

We also created a github project https://github.com/tezheng/UH5/. When the time comes we will open-source it.

Here is the first demo we release last week http://cyberytech.com:5000/mw2/. this is a COC style game, support iOS8 or Android 4.4+ (not PC-compatible now).

Comment: Is there any way for us to use it?